# How to resize bitmap to low resolution without loosing image information?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am creating a deep learning based android app. I have a `Canvas` where I am allowing the user to draw something. Then I will pass the bitmap of the `Canvas` to my model for classification. I am using [Tensorflow MNIST](https://github.com/miyosuda/TensorFlowAndroidMNIST) project as the base for my project. My problem is, in the MNIST example user are allowed to draw on a `28x28` size `Canvas`. But I don't want to do that because drawing on that `Canvas` is pixelating the drawing. I am drawing on a full size `Canvas` but while sending the `Bitmap` of the canvas to the `Tensorflow` model I want to resize it to `28x28` for classification (else I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`).

**How can I resize the bitmap to `28x28` without loosing information ?** or any other possible solution for this ?

**Here is the image of the MNIST canvas:**

[image]

**This is the image of my application canvas. I tried resizing it to 28x28 but I am loosing the image information:**

[image]

Comment: Unclear. Do you want to resize to 28x28? Or to 28x28 without loosing information?

Comment: 28x28 without loosing information @greenapps

Comment: That is impossible of course.

Comment: What can be alternative solution for this ? @greenapps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have an input of 100 x 100  image and you want to resize it to 28 x 28.

100 x 100 pixels -> 10000 features

28 x 28 pixels -> 784 features

It is mathematically impossible not to lose input information while resizing.

However there are other ways to work around.

- Get rid of white areas around drawing. It will already filter most of the unnecessary pixels. Then you can apply resizing.
- Try a different interpolation method. During the resizing operation, we are using different kinds of interpolations (bilinear, bicubic etc.).
- Try to make the input images bigger for your network (resize 28 x 28 MNIST to 56 x 56 for example) and train with bigger size. Then, you will be losing less information for inference in cost of speed as it will be slightly slower to classify larger image.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the alternatives. I am going with the 3rd option you provided. I trained the model with INPUT_SIZE 128